# iOS Sticker Packs - multiple or overlapping stickers cause previous stickers to distort or move

Tags: ios, message

I've testing a sticker pack - no code just add png images as stickers.  It is a christmas theme so users should be able to add multiple christmas decorations to an image.  A frequent problem seems to be that if you add a couple of stickers to the same image, it can distort previous stickers. For example, I have a christmas hat on the baby, I add a few extra decorations and the hat becomes stretched out /distorted on the recipients message.  [image: See sender vs. recipients message]

Comment: Show the relevant code

Comment: About an hour after I sent this.  I checked the recipients message again and stickers were back to where they should be.  Not sure if there is a delay sending data or something else going on but it certainly affects the user experience

Comment: Note that there is no code for sticker packs.  Xcode does everything.  You just add the images.  If only need to code for more complicated sticker features, e.g., changing background on stickers, changing the collection view sizes and format, adding IAP etc.  I haven't done any of that here.

Comment: I have recently publish [sticker app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pkcsticker/id1172768506?mt=8) to app store. I want to add IAP to this. Can you guide me how to implement IAP in sticker app please. Also how to add custom overlays to sticker like you add cap to baby in your screenshot.